# Servlet excecution in Tomcat 7

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I have installed JDK 1.7 and Tomcat 7.0. I am unable to execute basic servlet program. Kindly tell me the process of execution. And just give me details what are new things in Tomcat 7.0.

If I have to place any annotation like `@WebServlet`, tell me in which file I have to place and which packages I have to import.

*web.xml*

```
<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>kiru</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>DatesrvApp</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>kiru</servlet-name>
        <servlet-pattern>/classes/date</servlet-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

*DatesrvApp.java*

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class DatesrvApp extends GenericServlet {

    public void service(ServletRequest req,ServletResponse res)
                        throws ServletException, IOException {
        res.setContentType("text/html");    
        PrintWriter pw = res.getWriter();
        Date d = new Date();
        pw.println("<b><center>Date and Time is" + d.toString() + "</center></b>");
        pw.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: What url are you hitting ? What error do you get ?

Comment: `@WebServlet` annotation is used to substitute configurations in *web.xml*. It was introduced in Servlet version 3.0. So you can omit the related configurations in *web.xml*, even *web.xml* is optional. Just read these popular tutorials: [Beginning & Intermediate Servlet & JSP Tutorials](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html), they have simple examples, nice explanations, even contain setup instructions for Tomcat etc. Also check out [An Introduction To Servlet 3.0](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/10/14/introduction-to-servlet-3.html)

Answer (score 0):

`GenericServlet` servlet can't read your URL pattern, Please use `HttpServlet`.

Answer (score 0):

you should put

```
<url-pattern>/classes/date</url-pattern>
```

instead of

```
<servlet-pattern>/classes/date</servlet-pattern>
```

And put `servlet-api.jar` file from lib folder of the directory where Tomcat 7.0 is installed in your classpath.

Please use `HttpServlet` as suggested by Masud.